# Can i use for each in this program instead of for loop ? If yes them please show me how

Tags: java

```
class MissingArray
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int found=0;
        int[] array1={1,2,3,4,5};       
        int[] array2={2,3,1,0,5};
        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
        {
            found=0;
            for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++)
            {   
                if(array1[i]==array2[j])
                {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Missing Number is = " +array1[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here when I try to do "for each" I get this exception: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: Don't use `int found=0;` Java has `boolean`s for a reason.

Comment: I agree. My bad. but please help me with `for each`

Comment: Does @smarx 's answer work for you?

Comment: @bradimus Yes it does!!!

Comment: @smarx Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] array2 = {2, 3, 1, 0, 5};
    for (int num1 : array1)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int num2 : array2)
        {
            if (num1 == num2)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            System.out.println("Missing number is " + num1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a "for each" loop the code would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1={1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] array2={2,3,1,0,5};
    for (int a: array1) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int b: array2) {
            if (a == b)
                found = true;
        }
        if (!found)
            System.out.println("The missing number is "+a);
    }
}
```